# In a RESTful service : org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException (Table/View does not exist)

Tags: ejb, netbeans-8, restful-architecture, glassfish-4

I have been trying to create my first RESTful execrcise [using](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm). At first I faced error JDBC resource does not exist, I have created JDBC resource, JDBC connection pool that matches `glassfish-resources.xml` .

---

Now I encounter a different issue :

> "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]
>   (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View
>   'PLAYER' does not exist."

Could someone help me in where exactly should I be looking to rectify this issue.

---

Here is the view of persitence.xml and list of other services.

[image: persitence.xml]

---

GlassFish log:

> Warning:
>   StandardWrapperValve[com.playerentity.service.ApplicationConfig]:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet
>   com.playerentity.service.ApplicationConfig threw exception ERROR
>   42X05: Table/View 'PLAYER' does not exist.    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeSqlca(Unknown
>   Source)       at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown
>   Source)..45 more

Answer (score 0):

This is saying the table does not exists in the database ....it might be case sensitive if it is on a unix environment